# Nextjs config for JSX file type

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have created an Next 13 application where i have installed an package [@viral-loops/widgets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@viral-loops/widgets)

Once the package is installed and when i run the application i am getting the following error

```
error - ./node_modules/@viral-loops/widgets/dist/react/Widget.jsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (34:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|   return (
>     <>
|       {props.ucid ? (
|         <form-widget ucid={props.ucid} popup={props.popup} />
```

Here is my next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config, { isServer }) {
    const prefix = config.assetPrefix ?? config.basePath ?? '';
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack', 'url-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|mov|ogg|swf|ogv)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            options: {
              publicPath: `${prefix}/_next/static/videos/`,
              outputPath: `${isServer ? '../' : ''}static/videos/`,
              name: '[name]-[hash].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    );
    return config;
  },
  images: {
    disableStaticImages: true,
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'images.ctfassets.net',
        pathname: '**',
      },
    ],
  },
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'styles'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'styles/variables.scss'),
    ],
    prependData: '@import "./styles/variables.scss";',
  },
  compilerOptions: {
    baseUrl: '.',
    paths: {
      '@/components/*': ['components/*'],
    },
  },
};
```

I have tried setting up babel-loader like below in the next.config.js webpack

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config, { isServer }) {
    const prefix = config.assetPrefix ?? config.basePath ?? '';
    config.module.rules.push(
      **{test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, use: 'babel-loader'}**,
```

Which returns a new error like below

```
Syntax error: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (34:5):

  32 |
  33 |   return (
> 34 |     <>
     |     ^
  35 |       {props.ucid ? (
  36 |         <form-widget ucid={props.ucid} popup={props.popup} />
  37 |       ) : null}

Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

I am not sure where i have to add the @babel/preset-react in Nextjs application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the following to make the viral-loop widget to work in Next.js.

To Integrate ViralLoop with Next.js application install the below package

```
yarn add @viral-loops/widgets
```

Install babel/preset-react

```
Yarn add @babel/preset-react --save-dev
```

Once the installation is complete go to Next.config.js and add the following snippet to transpile JSX

```
{
       test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
       use: {
         loader: 'babel-loader',
         options: {
           presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
         },
       },
  },
```

[image]

Once the above steps are done the unexpected token issue was fixed but to import the widget i have to use the dynamic import like below

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const ViralLoopsWidget: any = dynamic(() => import('@viral-loops/widgets/dist/react').then((mod) => mod.ViralLoopsWidget), {ssr: false});
```

If the dynamic import is not needed then we can use the same inside an useEffect which will be called only on the client side render not on server side render

```
useEffect(() => {
    const viralLoopInit = async () => {
      const viralLoop = await import('@viral-loops/widgets/dist/react');
      console.log('viralLoop is', viralLoop);
      console.log('viralLoop1 is', await viralLoop.getCampaign());
    }
    viralLoopInit();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

Next.js is not able to transpile .jsx/css/scss files from node_modules directory.

You can use [`next-transpile-modules`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules). However, it is deprecated.

Since it is only one component that has this issue. You can create copy that component inside components' directory in your project root and use that component.

[image]

```
// @components/Widget

import * as React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Widget(props) {
  function loadViralLoops() {
    const SCRIPT_SRC = "https://app.viral-loops.com/widgetsV2/core/loader.js";
    const scriptExists = document.head.querySelector(
      `script[src="${SCRIPT_SRC}"]`
    );
    if (scriptExists) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = SCRIPT_SRC;
      script.onload = resolve;
      script.onerror = reject;
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadViralLoops().then(() => {
      const ViralLoops = globalThis["ViralLoops"];
      console.debug("[VL] -> load ViralLoops script", ViralLoops);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.debug("[VL] -> set props.ucid", props.ucid);
  }, ["[VL] -> set props.ucid", props.ucid]);

  return (
    <>
      {props.ucid ? (
        <form-widget ucid={props.ucid} popup={props.popup} />
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}

Widget.defaultProps = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Creating  a file `.babelrc` at the project level, and add this config and install added deps,

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"]
}
```